# Reactjs (javascript) how do I not see that the list is empty (Before) api gets called

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is the current code, when I load the list page, for a moment it says "No List Items Found", it then loads the items from the backend api afterwards and shows those items (the above message dissapears)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class List extends Component {

    // Initialize the state
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            list: [],
            isFetchedFromServer:false
        }
    }

    // Fetch the list on first mount
    componentDidMount() {
        this.getList();
    }

    // Retrieves the list of items from the Express app
    getList = () => {
        fetch('/api/getList')
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(list => this.setState({ list }))
            .then(this.state.isFetchedFromServer= true)
    }

    render() {
        const { list } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className="App">
            <h1>List of Items</h1>
        {/* Check to see if any items are found*/}
        {list.length ? (
            <div>
            {/* Render the list of items */}
            {list.map((item) => {
                    return(
                        <div>
                        {item}
                        </div>
                );
                })}
            </div>
        ) : (
        <div className={((this.state.list != undefined) &&( this.state.list != null)) ? '' : 'hidden'}>
        <h2>No List Items Found</h2>
        </div>
        )
        }
    </div>
    );
    }
}

export default List;
```

I would like to only see no list items found when it has returned from the backend call empty.

Please assist me in doing so.

Comment: Add the code of whole component. Also what exactly do you want? You api returns you an empty list but it's not rendering No list items found div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare a flag and update it after fetch is completed.

```
this.isShowMessage: false;

componentDidMount() {
        this.getList();
        this.isShowMessage: (this.state.list == null);
    }
```

And hide your div accordingly.

```
<div>
   {(this.isShowMessage) && <h2>No List Items Found</h2>}
</div>
```

Comment: I think we should have the variable flag inside the state. what do you say

Comment: Yep, better to keep it inside the state.

Comment: Nope, I still see that message, The only change I did was in componentDidMount `this.state.isFetchedFromServer = (this.state.list != null);` .

Comment: I even defined a css class called hidden but nope. I still see that message. Let me post my code above in the OP

Comment: Can you please try this?
<div className={(list != null) ?  " '' : 'hidden'}>
       <h2>No List Items Found</h2>
    </div>

Comment: Nope. still the same

Comment: I solved it by moving the hidden ahead to the other side. basically its your solution `<div className={(list)? 'hidden' : ''}>`

Answer (score 0):

As the Api is an Async Call , it initially says that the List is empty and after the response , the list is filled with objects. You may have to add a boolean `APIProcessing` in the state with initial value as true while the objects are still getting fetched from the database . After that you need to set to false and display the list

Answer (score 0):

What you are facing is absolutely fine. This is happening because it might take a small time for you app to get response from the API.

So till there is a response the length of this.state.list will be 0. Until that

### No List Items Found

will be shown.

You can negate the statement just to show it.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What you’re missing is a Boolean flag ‘isLoading’ in component state.

In your componentDidMount, set it to true. When your fetch has finished, set it to false.

Then, only show ‘No list items found.’ if isLoading is false and the list is empty.

Comment: Sure, I will try to add a boolean flag